# How to write dynamic SQL Query to copy items from table with proper MasterLevelId

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic, copy

I have a Budget table containing budget items. Each item has na ID (Autoincrement), BudgetId, BudgetItemLevel (some kind of level structure), BudgetItemCode(Not unique), BudgetItemName(not unique), BudgetItemMasterID (Connection to superior BudgetItem), BudgetItemValue, BudgetItemStatus and some DateTime values as shown bellow...

Each Budget can have a custom number of levels (BudgetId=1 -> 2 Levels; BudgetId=2 -> 3 levels and so on...).
BudgetItems with the BudgetItemMasterId = NULL are top level items...

[image]

What i need to do is to copy a Budget with its items(with exact same values as original) passing a BudgetId value to StoredProcedure. The difficult part here is to get the right BudgetMasterId for the new *copied* Budget items

Example

If i copy the BudgetId = 1, the new budget should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the final, full functional sp. Thank you all for your help...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CopyBudgetByBudgetId] 
@BudgetId int
AS
BEGIN
            DECLARE @identity int
            DECLARE @tempId int
            DECLARE @tempValue int

            INSERT INTO T_Budget ([BudgetName],[BudgetMaxLevel],[BudgetCurrency],[BudgetStatus],[BudgetAppliedToDonor],[sysDateTimeCreated],[sysDateTimeModified])
            SELECT [BudgetName],[BudgetMaxLevel],[BudgetCurrency],1,0,GETDATE(),GETDATE()
            FROM T_Budget
            WHERE ID = @BudgetId

            SELECT @identity= @@IDENTITY

            IF(@identity > 0)
            BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO T_BudgetCharts2([BudgetId],[BudgetItemLevel],[BudgetItemCode],[BudgetItemName],[BudgetItemMasterID],[BudgetItemBudegtValue],[BugedtItemStatus], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal],[sysDateTimeCreated],[sysDateTimeModified])
                    SELECT @identity,[BudgetItemLevel],[BudgetItemCode],[BudgetItemName],[BudgetItemMasterID],[BudgetItemBudegtValue],[BugedtItemStatus], [ID],[BudgetItemMasterID], GETDATE(),GETDATE()
                    FROM T_BudgetCharts2
                    WHERE BudgetId = @BudgetId

                    Declare @ID int
                    DECLARE IDs CURSOR LOCAL FOR (select ID from T_BudgetCharts2 where BudgetId = @identity)

                    OPEN IDs
                    FETCH NEXT FROM IDs into @ID

                    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                    BEGIN
                            If (Select MasterIdOriginal From T_BudgetCharts2 Where ID = @ID) IS NOT NULL
                                BEGIN
                                SET @tempId = (Select MasterIdOriginal From T_BudgetCharts2 Where ID = @ID)
                                SET @tempValue = (Select ID FROM T_BudgetCharts2 WHERE BugedtIdOriginal = @tempId) 
                                Update T_BudgetCharts2 SET BudgetItemMasterId = @tempValue WHERE ID = @ID
                            END
                            FETCH NEXT FROM IDs into @ID
                    END

                    CLOSE IDs
                    DEALLOCATE IDs
            END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay lets say you pass BudgetID 1 to your sproc.  I would create a loop that works off the top level items.  So lets go with ID number 1.  Create a row for this because it is top level and put the ID in a variable.  After that loop through everything that has budget ID one and has a budgetmasterid equal to ID 1 and create those rows and give them the budgetmasterid of the new top level item you created.

```
DECLARE @identity int
DECLARE @tempId int
DECLARE @tempMasterId int

SELECT @identity = @@IDENTITY
IF(@identity > 0)


Declare @MasterID int
DECLARE MasterIDs CURSOR LOCAL FOR (select Id from T_BudgetCharts where BudgetId = @BudgetId )
OPEN MasterIDs
FETCH NEXT FROM BudgetIds into @MasterID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

IF((Select [BudgetItemMasterID] from T_BudgetCharts where [Id] = @MasterID)is not null)
INSERT INTO T_BudgetCharts([BudgetId],[BudgetItemLevel],[BudgetItemCode],[BudgetItemName],[BudgetItemMasterID],[BudgetItemBudegtValue],[BugedtItemStatus], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal],[sysDateTimeCreated],[sysDateTimeModified])
SELECT @identity,[BudgetItemLevel],[BudgetItemCode],[BudgetItemName],[BudgetItemMasterID],[BudgetItemBudegtValue],[BugedtItemStatus], [ID],[BudgetItemMasterID], GETDATE(),GETDATE()
FROM T_BudgetCharts
WHERE [Id] = @MasterID
Declare @NewMasterID int
set @NewMasterID = @@IDENTITY

INSERT INTO T_BudgetCharts([BudgetId],[BudgetItemLevel],[BudgetItemCode],[BudgetItemName],[BudgetItemMasterID],[BudgetItemBudegtValue],[BugedtItemStatus], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal],[sysDateTimeCreated],[sysDateTimeModified])
SELECT @identity,[BudgetItemLevel],[BudgetItemCode],       [BudgetItemName],@NewMasterID,[BudgetItemBudegtValue],[BugedtItemStatus], [ID],            [BudgetItemMasterID], GETDATE(),GETDATE()
FROM T_BudgetCharts
Where [BudgetItemMasterID] = @MasterID
END
END
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried that didn't work? Or is it the concept that is problematic?