# Duplicating a row with all the rows below it in the hierarchy tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I do not know if my request has a name but I think it can be called "duplicating a row with all the rows below it in the hierarchy tables".

I want to create a stored procedure that can duplicate a record and all its childs and grandchilds records.

When I say "Duplicate" I main that all the record values in the columns will be copy to a new record on the same table (the copy should be without Primary key Id column because its automated)
This Stored Procedure needs to get two parameters:

1. Parameter 1 - Table Name
2. Parameter 2 - Value of the Primary key Id (of that Table Name) that needs to duplicate.

Instructions of the code:

1. The value (Parameter 2) will find one record on the table (Parameter 1) and duplicate it (as I said same values for all the columns excluding the primary key of that table.
2. Then we will need to know all the table names that has a relationship with this primary key (of the parent table)
3. Then every child table will duplicate the records that have the same Id value (Parameter 2) with the new Id value (of the new parent record).

several things:
In the dream scenario the code knows to go down levels without any limit (children, grandchildren, great-grandchildren ...) ,but I guess it is a very complex code that will contain some recursion code, so even a code containing up to 3-4 levels I will be happily accepted.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Its a general question, I am afraid I will present an example and the solution will be only for the example and not for the question.

Comment: . . You are probably better off with an answer to a specific question than no answer to a general question.

Comment: This really depends on your data structure.  Are all your parent and child records in one table that self references or is there a separate relationship table or perhaps something else altogether.

Comment: This is doable with dynamic SQL, assuming all your keys are the same type and have defaults. You need to a proc that accepts a list of PKs in a TVP @`toCopy`, will create an `insert` statement for a given table (`sys.columns`), excluding PK columns, and `output inserted.PK into @table1`, then cursor over each table that references this one (`sys.foreign_keys`) and do another dynamic SQL query: selecting matching rows from the child tables join `@table` and inserting their PKs into `@table2`. Then you recursively call the proc with the child table name and `@table2`

Comment: Make a start on that and come back if you need help. Although why you want to do this is beyond me.

Comment: @Charlieface I have no idea how to do such a thing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically copy data from one table to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61402495/dynamically-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another) Also this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882883/how-to-write-dynamic-sql-query-to-copy-items-from-table-with-proper-masterleveli